# In a parent process, how to see child variables that are managed by child processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, child-process

I defined a class Node, which defines a listener service to constantly communicate and update local variables. The listener is started using multiprocessing. The class looks like:

```
# Pseudo-code
import multiprocessing
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.variables = x
    def listener(self):
        while(True):
            COMMUNICATE WITH OTHERS     # Pseudo-code
            UPDATE self.variable        # Pseudo-code
            print(self.variable)        # local printer
    def run(self):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.listener)
        p.start()
```

In the main process, I created two nodes a = Node(x1), b = Node(x2), and let them run

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x1 = 1       # for example
    x2 = 1000    # for example
    a = Node(x1)
    b = Node(x2)

    a.run()
    b.run()

    while(True):
        print(a.variable)        # global printer
        print(b.variable)        # global printer
```

In this way, Node-a communicates with Node-b and updates its variables, and so does Node-b.

**Now I come with a problem: Local printers output updated variable values correctly, but global printers do not.** Actually, the global printers always output unchanged values (x1, x2, same as initial).

What's wrong with the code Or how to see the child process variables?

Comment: For most practical purposes, you can't see the variables in another process unless you're using a debugger or you locate the variables in shared memory (and then ensure that you don't have concurrent access from different processes).  Or, it can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that unless you use any mechanism to communicate with the parent. I recommend you use Manager dicts.

```py
import random
import time
import multiprocessing as mp


class Child(mp.Process):

    def __init__(self, shared_variables):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.shared_variables = shared_variables

    def run(self):
        for _ in range(5): # Change shared variable value 5 times
            self.shared_variables['var'] = random.randint(0, 10)
            self.shared_variables['var1'] = random.randint(0, 10)
            time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    shared_variables = mp.Manager().dict()
    child = Child(shared_variables)
    child.start()

    while True:
        print('Form parent')
        for k, v in shared_variables.items():
            print(f'-> {k}: {v}')
        print('***********')
        time.sleep(3)
```

And the output would look like this:

```
Form parent
-> var: 8
-> var1: 6
***********
Form parent
-> var: 7
-> var1: 7
***********
....
```